# for loop together with if statement override PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of PHP code:

```
for($i=0;$i<$rowsize;$i++) {

            if($i == $object_id) {

                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT x, y, src FROM house_room1 INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id WHERE ref_id = ?')) {

                /* Bind parametres */
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $ref_id);

                /* Insert the parameter values */
                $ref_id = $i;

                /* Execute the query */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* Bind resultatet */
                $stmt->bind_result($x, $y, $src);

                /* Close statement */
                $stmt->close();

                } else {
                /* Something went wrong */
                echo 'Something went terrible wrong'     . $mysqli->error;
                }
                echo '<img src="'.$src; echo '"class="item" style="position:relative; left:'.$x; echo 'px; top:'.$y; echo 'px;">';

            }
        }
```

This code starts with a for-loop that loops through a database table that currently cotains two rows. While it does that, it says that if variable `$i` is equal to an object id inside the database, then execute this query which finds a `src`, `x` and `y` from the database. After that, it inserts these values in a image to make the image display on the page. However even though there are two rows that it has to go through, and therefore two images that has to be displayed, it's like it is overriding the first image since only the last image is shown. I think it has to do with my PHP logic but I can't figure out how to display both images without any getting overrided. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first you didn't loop the inside images display. second what is the value of your `$x` and `$y`. they are same will display the image on same position as your css applied.

Comment: and $x and $y values are two different values in the database, and the object_id differs from 1 and 2. So do I need to loop through the images as well to get them all displayed? hm and how so?

Comment: try once to remove your style in image.

Comment: try adding a debug statement after $stmt->bind_result($x, $y, $src); or debug using NetBeans, are you sure you are retrieving 2 values from the database?

Comment: also to make things simpler, you can just echo the image in 1 echo statement:

echo '<img src="'.$src . '"class="item" style="position:relative; left:' .$x 'px; top:'.$y; echo 'px;">';

Comment: @AminM well since query is repeated twice because of the for-loop, I guess I should retrieve 2 values from the database since it shows one of the images correctly. It's just like it overrides the if-statement at the next for-loop increment

Comment: Where do you get $object_id from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare('SELECT x, y, src FROM house_room1 INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id WHERE objects.object_id = ?'); 
$stmt->bind_param('i', $object_id);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($x, $y, $src);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo '<img src="' . $src . '" class="item" style="position:relative; left:' . $x . ' px; top:' . $y . 'px;">';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Something went terrible wrong' . $mysqli->error;
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: Uhm I tried to replace your code with mine but no images are displayed now at all? mhmm

Comment: I've updated my answer. Perhaps it was because it was being closed before the data was fetched. Hopefully it should now work :)

Comment: Okay, try once again :) I've changed the formatting of it, and used the fetch_array method instead.

Comment: It now have an error on line: `$result = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` 
That says: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()

Comment: Changed it back to using bind_result, and also added a fetch after the line. It might work lol.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48052/discussion-between-user3287771-and-weiver)